# Mongoose : Add an element to an array of Objects under an Object field

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongoose

I'm trying to add an element to an array of Objects under an Object field
This in my mongoose "Utilisateur" schema:
[image]

So what i'm trying to do here is to add an element to the "lien_vers" array
this is the code that i wrote

```
  Utilisateur.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(auteur._id) },

                          {
                            $push: {
                              'relations.lien_vers': {
                                metadonnees: { nom_societe: societePersonalId },
                                identite: auteur._id.toString(),
                                canons: [""]

                              }
                            }
                          }, { upsert: true }
                          , function (error, doc) {
                            if (err) {
                              console.log("Something wrong when updating data!", err);
                            }

                            console.log("updated", doc.relations);
                          });
```

i've got no errors but there is no changes ! it seems like the update is not working correctly
Any help plz

Answer (score 1):

> By default, `findOneAndUpdate()` returns the document as it was before update was applied. If you set `new: true`, `findOneAndUpdate()` will instead give you the object after update was applied.

Your code looks fine, the record is updated in your db, it just return the document before update in your callback. To get the updated document, you just need to add `new: true` to the options.

Comment: There is no changes in my db ! i ve checked

Comment: i tried this solution with findOne then push then save and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Eventually this solution worked for me

I insist on adding `markModified()` so that the `save()` method can detect changes

```
  Utilisateur.findOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(auteur._id) }, function (err, sal) {
                          if (err) return handleError(err);
                          else {


                            sal.relations.lien_vers.push({
                              metadonnees: { nom_societe: societePersonalId },
                              identite: auteur._id.toString(),
                              canons: [""]
                            });

                            console.log("before saving", sal.relations.lien_vers)
                            sal.markModified('relations');
                            sal.save(function (err) {
                              if (err) {
                                console.log(err)
                              }
                              console.log("doc saved")
                            });




                          }

                        });

                      }
```